# List of metrics that can be passed to tf.keras.model.compile

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, deep-learning, tf.keras

Based on the [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile), when compiling a model, I can specify one or more metrics to use, such as 'accuracy' and  'mse'. However, the documentation doesn't say what metrics are available. I tried to replace 'accuracy' with a few other classical metrics such as 'recall' or 'auc', but that didn't work.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['recall'])
```

What metrics are available? Where can I find a list of all the metrics keywords I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the following (usually with relation to a classification task)

1. **Accuracy** via:

   ```
   keras.metrics.accuracy(y_true, y_pred)
   ```
2. **Binary Accuracy** given a certain thershold:

   ```
   keras.metrics.binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, threshold=0.5)
   ```
3. **Categorical Accuracy** via:

   ```
   keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred)
   ```
4. **Sparse Categorical Accuracy** via:

   ```
   keras.metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred)
   ```
5. **Sparse Categorical Accuracy** given a certain k:

   ```
   keras.metrics.top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=5)
   ```
6. **Sparse Categorical Accuracy**  given a certain k:

   ```
   keras.metrics.top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=5)
   ```
7. **Cosine Proximity**  given a certain axis:

   ```
   keras.metrics.cosine_proximity(y_true, y_pred, axis=-1)
   ```

In addition to the metrics above, you may use any of the **loss** functions described in the loss function page as metrics.
You may also implement your own custom metric, for example:

```
import keras.backend as K

def mean_pred(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_pred)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy', mean_pred])
```

Reference: [Keras Metrics](https://keras.io/metrics/), [Keras Loss Functions](https://keras.io/losses/)

Answer (score 2):

Try using one of the metrics from here: https://keras.io/metrics/